# No data found in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to get an employee that does not have a manager to show on my table but all im getting is "no data found" when i know that such employee exist in the db.

this is my code:

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please Enter Employee ID:'

declare 
  v_eid               employee.employee_id%TYPE := &p_1;
  v_count             NUMBER;
  v_name              employee.employee_name%TYPE;
  v_sal               employee.salary%type;
  v_mname             employee.employee_id%TYPE ;
  v_dptname           department.department_name%type;  
  v_avg               employee.salary%type;

BEGIN 
  SELECT count(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM employee
  WHERE employee_id = v_eid;

  IF v_count = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_eid || ' is not in the table.');
  ELSE
      select e1.employee_name, e1.salary, department.department_name,
             nvl(e2.employee_name, 0)
      into v_name, v_sal, v_mname, v_dptname
      from employee e1
      inner join employee e2 on e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id 
      inner join department on e1.department_id = department.department_id
      where e1.employee_id = v_eid;

      select AVG(salary)
      into v_avg
      from employee
      where department_id = (select department_id 
                              from employee 
                              where employee_id=v_eid);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name:'|| LPAD(v_name,30));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary:'|| LPAD(to_char(v_sal,'$9,999.00'),28));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Manager Name:'|| LPAD(v_mname, 19));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department Name:'|| v_dptname);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department Average'|| to_char(v_avg,'$9,999.00'));
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi If you are looking only for employees without manager why are you doing a self join.In any case if no manager exists you should replace

```
from employee e1 inner join employee e2 on e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id 

by

from employee e1 left outer join employee e2 on e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id
```

Comment: I am looking foe employees in general. In case when an employee does not have a manager I want to be able to see it. The first part checks for the employee and the second for their information where I have the 2 cases. Either they have a mngr or they dont

Answer (score 6):

In general, don't first check if a record exists but just do the query. If at that moment the records does not exist catch the exception.

```
begin
   select...

exception
   when no_data_found then
      xyz is not in the table
end;
```

This is better because you only query once. Also the record may, at least theoretically, get deleted between your check and the second query. So you still need your exception handler.

Comment: I am not allowed to use exceptions on this one thats why